# Local database "no format for SQL server Compact" after OneDrive download of .sdf file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce, windows-phone-8.1

I upload my database of my app into OneDrive as a `.SDF` file with this line:

```
iso.CopyFile(AppResources.DatabaseName + ".sdf", "/shared/transfers/" + databaseBackupname + ".sdf");

LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(oneDriveAuthClient.Session);

try
{
   LiveOperationResult uploadResult = await liveClient.BackgroundUploadAsync(oneDriveFolderId, new Uri("/shared/transfers/" + databaseBackupname + ".sdf", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
```

After this I can successfully download this file with this code:

```
string tmpPathDatabase = "\\shared\\transfers\\downloadedDatabase.sdf";
LiveOperationResult downloadResult = await liveClient.BackgroundDownloadAsync(file.FileID, new Uri(tmpPathDatabase, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Until I try to use the file as a database everything works fine. But when I try to use the file in this code:

```
string tmpDBConnectionString = "Data Source=isostore:" + tmpPathDatabase;

using (DBClass tmpDB = new DBClass(tmpDBConnectionString))
{
    if (tmpDB.DatabaseExists() == true)
    {
        DatabaseSchemaUpdater dbNewUpdater = tmpDB.CreateDatabaseSchemaUpdater();
```

I get the error message when creating the `DatabaseSchemaUpdater`:

> The file that is being referenced is not a SQL Server Compact database file format 
>   [ Databasename = C:\Data\Users\DefApps\APPDATA\Local\Packages\xxx.TimecardApp_evtaxn4jfh7hw\LocalState\downloadedDatabase.sdf ]

Does the up- or download change the coding of files? Because when I just copy the files in the IsolatedStorage I can use them as databases without any changes. I thought the same about using OneDrive.

Comment: Would it be better to change the backup file into a database.bak file?

Comment: Can you do a file compare to check if the binary content changes?

Comment: between the sdf file in the isolated storage and onedrive? Will do, but not now. I'm at work right now.

Comment: What I could do right now is to check the sdf file uploaded to OneDrive with MS SQL management 2008 and can say, the files is not corrupt. I can query it and it delivers the correct data. Can it be, that the download of the file above isn't really finished? Altough the BackgroundDownload method is finished?

Comment: Yes, of course, it will just start a background operation and return. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219338.aspx

Comment: First: I changed the BackgroundDownloadAsync method against the DownloadAsync method. But the same error occurs when trying to use the .sdf file as database file. But I checked the .sdf save in OneDrive with the CompactViewer (which is from you ;) ) and the database works and is correct. I tried to get the file from iso storage with this:
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Tools\IsolatedStorageEx
plorerTool>ISETool.exe ts xd <productID> "C:\Users\Geor
gDeveloper\Documents"' but this always started a new Emulator and not the one which was alreday running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a noob mistake. Solution is simple:

```
await liveClient.DownloadAsync(file.FileID + "/content");
```

Pretty sure it would work with DownloadBackgroundAsync too.

I missed the `/content`. Thought the fileID would be enough and the Live SDK API knows what to do, when downloading a file (not just getting the properties) The download stream was almost empty. Found this out when I directly uploaded the file again to OneDrive and saw that it was just 2KB big.